# R: Greek letters in ylab of `plot.ts()`

Tags: r, plot, time-series

`plot.ts()` provides a convenient way to visualize multivariate time series. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to annotate the (repeated) horizontal axes with Greek letters. The familiar approach for inserting Greek letters seems not to work and nor do some less clever approaches I've tried:

```
testdata = matrix(rnorm(300), ncol = 3)
# doesn't work
plot.ts(testdata, ylab = expression(paste(pi[0], " = 0")))
# doesn't work
plot.ts(testdata, ylab = c(expression(paste(pi[0], " = 0")),
                           expression(paste(pi[0], " = 1")),
                           expression(paste(pi[0], " = 2"))))
# doesn't work
colnames(testdata) = c(expression(paste(pi[0], " = 0")),
                       expression(paste(pi[0], " = 1")),
                       expression(paste(pi[0], " = 2")))
plot.ts(testdata)
# doesn't work
plot.ts(testdata, ylab = parse(text = y))
```

I've run out of ideas ...

Comment: Not possible with just `plot.ts`. As it seems, `plot.ts` draws the y-labels from the `colnames` of `x` which must be of type character. If these are `NULL`, then `plot.ts` constructs these as Series 1, Series 2,... and so on as in the examples you provided. The `ylab` argument is being ignored for that purpose.

Comment: The only way of getting something similar is setting `par("ann")=FALSE`, after which the y-labels can be written manually using `mtext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution using `library(zoo)`

```
testdata = matrix(rnorm(300), ncol = 3)
plot(zoo::as.zoo(testdata),ylab=c(expression(mu),expression(sigma),expression(beta)),main="Win!")
```

[image]

adapted from http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-change-the-label-in-plot-ts-td796114.html